# Upload Build using CURL

Tags: c++, curl, artifactory, conan

I've been trying to find a way to upload builds to artifactory using CURL. I know that we can easily send packages, but i can't find info on sending builds that will land here:

[Artifactory Build Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Vuh.png)

Thanks !

Comment: Hi Pedro. If you mean how to upload the ``build-info`` that you have built with the ``conan_build_info`` command, there is no conan command to upload it, but you might use the ``JFrog-cli`` to upload it. There might be instructions how to upload a generic build-info to Artifactory in the Artifactory docs, like this one: https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-build-info-json-file-via-the-rest-api/. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, builds are published in two steps:

1. The artifacts belonging to the build are deployed. To tie these artifacts to the build, they must have two properties: `build.name` set to the build name, and `build.number` set to the build number. If these properties are not set correctly, Artifactory won't know that they belong to your build.
2. The build info file is uploaded. This isn't an artifact, and it uses a special REST API ([this one](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-BuildUpload)). The build info file itself is a JSON file describing the build, and contains the build name and number, the checksums for all the files belonging to the build, and a lot of other (mostly optional) information. This is usually generated by a build tool, but the above link to the REST API has an example file that can be used as a reference to make one from scratch, if you really need it. An example for uploading a build info file:

   ```
   curl -XPUT http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/build -H "Content-Type: application/json" -T build.json
   ```

---

In your specific case, you appear to be using Conan. You can take a look at [this](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.4/howtos/generic_ci_artifactory.html), which documents how to generate and upload a build info file. Steps:

1. Set the `CONAN_TRACE_FILE` environment variable to a file path. This logs your build information to a trace file that can be converted to a build info file.
2. In your Conan home, create a file `artifacts.properties`. This file tells Conan to add specific properties (including the `build.name` and `build.number` required for deploying a build) whenever it deploys an artifact. An example `artifacts.properties` file:

   ```
   artifact_property_build.name=MyBuild
   artifact_property_build.number=23
   artifact_property_build.timestamp=1487676992
   ```
3. Run all of your build steps, including deploying the artifacts. Each step will log to the file you set in `CONAN_TRACE_FILE`.
4. Run the `conan_build_info` command and pass it the path to the `CONAN_TRACE_FILE`. This will generate an appropriate build info file.

   ```
   conan_build_info /tmp/traces.log --output /tmp/build_info.json
   ```
5. The newly generated build info file can now be uploaded to Artifactory using curl, as described above.

---

You can also publish a build using the JFrog CLI (documentation [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-BuildIntegration-PublishingaBuild))

Comment: thank you very much for your answer ! I'm using conan to host dependencies and then the build runs using cmake in a Bamboo instance. Since we dont have Artifactory's Bamboo plugin, we wanted to send the build artifacts from Bamboo to Artifactory in a "Generic" fashion. So, this build.json will refer all the build metadata i need, but does it send the files refered in it (the build outputs) ? I want to host the build results in the artifactory too.

Comment: In step 3, "Run all of your build steps, including deploying the artifacts." The documentation I linked has an example using `conan upload`. I'm pretty sure doing this is what causes the artifacts to show up properly in the build info file in the first place.